# How to display a JLabel without a layout manager

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, layout, jlabel

I am making a game for a final project and I need to have a label which is a big "X" appear in the middle of a JPanel. I have the JPanels appearing but the label will not appear because I dont have a layout manager, but if I use a layout manager my entire project gets changed. This is the project I have to do so you can see what I'm trying to do.

> Create a game that helps new mouse users improve their hand-eye coordination. Within a JFrame,       display an array of 48 JPanels in a GridLayout using eight rows and six columns. Randomly display an X on one of the panels. When the user clicks the correct panel(the one displaying the X), remove the X and display it on a different panel. After the user has successfully “hit” the correct panel 10 times, display a congratulation message that includes the user’s percentage(hits divided by clicks). Save the file as JCatchTheMouse.java.

Here's my code

```
package CatchTheMouse;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CatchTheMouse extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener{
    final int ROWS = 8;
    final int COLS = 6;
    final int GAP = 2;
    final int MAX_PANELS = ROWS * COLS;
    int clicks;
    int hits;
    int percentage = 0;
    int width;
    int height;
    int panelX;
    int panelY;
    int whichPanel = (int)(Math.random() * 48 + 1);
    int numberOfPanels = 1;

    JLabel grats = new JLabel("");
    JLabel spot = new JLabel("X");
    JPanel[] panel = new JPanel[MAX_PANELS];
    JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS, GAP, GAP));
    Font xFont = new Font("Ariel", Font.BOLD, 30);
    Font font = new Font("Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 12);

    public CatchTheMouse() {
        super("Catch the Mouse");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300,300);
        add(spot);
        spot.setFont(xFont);
        add(grats);
        grats.setFont(font);
        add(pane);
        for(int x = 0; x < MAX_PANELS; ++x) {
            panel[x] = new JPanel();
            pane.add(panel[x]);
            panel[x].setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
        pane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panelX = panel[whichPanel].getX();
        panelY = panel[whichPanel].getY();
        width = panel[whichPanel].getWidth() / 2;
        height = panel[whichPanel].getHeight() / 2;
        spot.setBounds(panelX, panelY, width, height);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        clicks = e.getClickCount();
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {    
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {    
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CatchTheMouse frame = new CatchTheMouse();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Font xFont = new Font("Ariel", Font.BOLD, 30);`  It is spelled 'Arial' (no 'E'), and probably only available on Windows.  For both reasons it is better to use `Font.SANS_SERIF` which 1) can be checked at compile time. 2) Is cross platform.  I.E. it will use Arial font on Windows, Helvetica font on OS X, and the default undecorated ('san serif') font on Unix/Linux..

Comment: *"How to display a JLabel without a layout manager"*  BTW - why are you trying to do this without using a layout manager when the problem description explicitly states *"..display an array of 48 JPanels **in a GridLayout**.."*?

Answer (score 0):

your spot is being drawn behind all the other panels. if you add

```
setComponentZOrder(spot, 0);
```

this will cause it to be drawn on top of everything else.

A better way to approach this would be to draw the x inside of the panels that you have instead of on top of them.

EDIT:

you can add your x to a specific panel with

```
panel[0].add(spot);
```

Comment: How would I do that? I just tried that but it now only displays the X and nothing else

Comment: @buckley183 I meant dont do it that way (adding the x to the main panel) but if you did you have to figure out how to make the background of the label transparent

Answer (score 0):

Make another `JPanel` and place it inside the first `JPanel`. Add the `JLabel` and the `Layout` to the second `JPanel`, the one inside the first.

Set nested-`JPanel` and other coordinates' positions accordingly.